# Zebra labels Code 128 subset A

Tags: zebra-printers

I am trying to do something pretty simple, just create a label on a Zebra printer using the Code 128 bar code, subset A (upper case, digits and some special characters).

The default for the font is subset B, so the instructions say to put the start character in the barcode text of the label instructions (>9).

However, after I do that all it prints is (Start value)(space value)(stop value).

Here is my labels text.

^XA
^MMT
^MNY
^LL600
^LH100,100
^FO0,0
^BY9
^BC,150,N,N,N,N^FD>9AB
^FS
^XZ

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. For some reason I need to translate my characters into the barcode 'values' first. So 'A' would be 33.

^BC,150,N,N,N,N^FD>933

Weird that that is the only subset that does that. They also did not explain it very well in their documentation.